# How to fix 'Expected stackmap frame at this location' in a Jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm maintaining a jenkins plugin, which has been in public use for two years. Recently, it stopped working showing the '*Expected stackmap frame at this location*' JVM error.

There are some SO topics discussing this problem, but none of the answers really provide a useful solution. One suggested solution is to configure the JVM with the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier option. However, this is not practical by enforcing every jenkins server installation to update its JVM configuration.

What I have done so far is to set the Java compilation version to 7 and updated all MVN dependencies to their latest version and performed clean rebuilds. So far without any progress. I still get this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 53
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/loadimpact/ApiTokenClient.isValidToken()Z @0: aload_0
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 00db 12ac b901 5902 0004 bd01 5f59
    0x0000010: 03b2 0163 53b9 0167 0200 b901 cf01 004c
    0x0000020: 2bb6 017f b901 d301 00b2 01d7 a600 0704
    0x0000030: a700 0403 ac4c 2ab4 00d7 bb01 d959 b701
    0x0000040: da13 01dc b601 e02b b601 e3b6 01e5 b601
    0x0000050: e803 ac                                
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 52] => handler: 53

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
```

My test environment is Ubuntu 15.04, with OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14) running the latest Jenkins (version 1.611).

The plugin depends (now) on the latest jenkins parent plugin

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.610</version>
</parent>
```

So, my question is simply: How do I fix this problem, given that I can only specify dependencies and compilation options for the plugin (i.e. not asking people to change their Jenkins configs)?

Comment: If you are the one who compiles the maven plugin, compilation with `source=1.6` and `target=1.6.` should solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Jenkins plugin I'm building with Gradle  and "Gradle JPI" plugin. everything works fine locally, but then jenkins throws this exception when invoking the plugin code, even though I use the same JDK version when building the Jenkins plugin and running that Jenkins server instance.

Comment: correction: turned out it only works locally when I run Jenkins in debug mode through "gradle server" command and it does not work if I run it using "java -jar -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -DJENKINS_HOME=./work /opt/jenkins-620.war"

Comment: @jens.riboe, does your project (or the libraries you use) use Lombok by any chance? I found that my jenkins failure was inside a library I was using that had some "lombok" steps. so far it looks like I should just get rid of that dependency